# Access Facebook page data using Android

Tags: android

Is there any way to access a Facebook non-user page (ex: Musician, Product, etc) through an API through Android? I saw that there is a Facebook Android SDK but I haven't been able to figure out if this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done. Have a look at the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) docs from facebook. I don't have very much insight into exactly how this is done with Android but the SDK should have example code to get you on the right track.